# How can I count seconds as days in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to count seconds in Unity as days so 1 second is = 1 day.
I have in the scene an empty object TimeManager with this script attached (TimeManager.cs):

```
    public class TimeManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    float elapsedTime;                
    bool dayElapsed;
    public float RealTimestep = 1f; // 1 second in realtime
    public float SimulationTimestep = 86400f; // seconds = 1 day in simulation time
    float simulationRatio; // Ratio of realtime to simulation time.
    float t = 0; // T represents total time that has passed within the simulation (not realtime)


    public float T
    {
        get { return t; }
    }    

    public bool IsDayElapsed
    {
        get { return dayElapsed; }
        set { dayElapsed = value; }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        simulationRatio = SimulationTimestep / RealTimestep;            
        t = 0;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        float timeElapsed = Time.deltaTime * simulationRatio;
        t += timeElapsed;
        
        Debug.Log(string.Format("Time.deltaTime: {0} simulationRatio: {1} timeElapsed: {2} t: {3}", Time.deltaTime, simulationRatio, timeElapsed, t));            
        dayElapsed = false;
        if (timeElapsed >= RealTimestep)
        {
            dayElapsed = true;
        }
    }
```

The Debug.Log into the Update() returns:

```
Time.deltaTime: 0,0160148 simulationRatio: 86400 timeElapsed: 1383,679 t: 208822,2
```

As showed above, I don't have a match between seconds and days.
Also, If the simulation continues to run, after 366 seconds, the days should be counted from 1 again:

```
// ╔═════════╦══════╗
// ║ Seconds ║ Days ║
// ╠═════════╬══════╣
// ║       1 ║    1 ║
// ║       3 ║    3 ║
// ║     ... ║  ... ║
// ║     365 ║  365 ║
// ║     366 ║    1 ║
// ║     367 ║    2 ║
// ║     ... ║  ... ║
// ╚═════════╩══════╝
```

I think somewhere should be integrated something like this:

```
var minRange = 1;
var maxRange = 365;
        
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var days = i % (maxRange - minRange + 1) + minRange;
}
```

Comment: Sounds very probable. Although a for loop wouldn’t be necessary

Comment: Could you make your problem and question a bit more clear? Are you just generally saying the time doesn't match and you want us to fix it? Or is there something a bit more specific? (Either are fine, I'm just checking)

Comment: The time doesn't match and I don't know how to fix it. As I wrote above, I need to count the seconds of simulation as days, I thought the code written above would give me the solution, but I was obviously wrong... So, please, help me fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code shold solve the problem:

```
public class TimeManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    float rate, days;
    int seconds;

    private void Update()
    {
        rate += Time.deltaTime;

        if (rate > 1)
        {
            rate = 0;
            seconds++;
            days++;
        }

        if (days > 365)
        {
            days = 0;
        }

        Debug.Log("Current seconds: " + seconds + " Days: " + days + " Rate: " + rate);
    }
}
```